# Use dplyr´s filter and mutate to generate a new variable

Tags: r, dplyr

i choose the hflights-dataset as an example.

I try to create a variable/column that contains the "TailNum" from the planes, but only for the planes that are under the 10% with the longest airtime.

```
install.packages("hflights") 
library("hflights") 
flights <-tbl_df(hflights) 
flights %>% filter(cume_dist(desc(AirTime)) < 0.1) %>% mutate(new_var=TailNum)
```

EDIT: The resulting dataframe has only 22208 obs instead of 227496. Is there a way to keep the original dataframe, but add a new variable with the TeilNum for the planes with top10-percent airtime?

Comment: It is creating a variable `new`. `mutate(new=TailNum)` Check the `glimpse(flights1)` `$ new               (chr) "N614AS", "N627AS", "N627AS", "N618AS", "N607AS",...`

Comment: With `%>%` you don't need to specify the `flights` within  `mutate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `flights` in `mutate()` after the pipe.

```
flights %>% filter(cume_dist(desc(AirTime)) < 0.1) %>% mutate(new = TailNum)
```

Also, new is a function, so best avoid that as a variable name. See ?new. 
As an illustration:

```
flights <-tbl_df(hflights) 
flights %>% filter(cume_dist(desc(AirTime)) < 0.1) %>% 
+   mutate(new_var = TailNum, new = TailNum) %>%
+   select(AirTime, TailNum, new_var)
Source: local data frame [22,208 x 3]

   AirTime TailNum new_var
1      255  N614AS  N614AS
2      257  N627AS  N627AS
3      260  N627AS  N627AS
4      268  N618AS  N618AS
5      273  N607AS  N607AS
6      278  N624AS  N624AS
7      274  N611AS  N611AS
8      269  N607AS  N607AS
9      253  N609AS  N609AS
10     315  N626AS  N626AS
..     ...     ...     ...
```

To retain all observations, lose the `filter()`. My normal approach is to use `ifelse()` instead. Others may be able to suggest a better solution.

```
f2 <- flights %>% mutate(cumdist = cume_dist(desc(AirTime)), 
                   new_var = ifelse(cumdist < 0.1, TailNum, NA)) %>%
  select(AirTime, TailNum, cumdist, new_var)

table(is.na(f2$new_var))

 FALSE   TRUE 
 22208 205288
```

Comment: `replace` was 2x faster than `ifelse` on my 1e6 dataset